# Oracle Enterprise Manager license

Tags: oracle-11g

I read somewhere that OEM comes along with Oracle Database, but does it require some management license and how the license is counted? is it per physical/LDOM server based or per control domain based or per processor based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The license packs for OEM (and Grid Control) are sold by "named user plus" or by cpu.
You can find the details of the price on [Oracle website](https://shop.oracle.com/pls/ostore/product?p1=databasemanagementpacks).

Beware, there are some minimum quantities that vary according to the metric you choose or to the license of your database.